# Complex Roots of $(z^2 - i)^2 = -4$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I'm having a bit of trouble finding the complex roots of the equation

$$ (z^2 - i)^2 = -4 $$

I've first taken the root of both sides to come up with

$$ z^2 - i = -2i $$

and then attempted to isolate the $ z $ on the left side and I end up with the following options
 $$
    z^2 = \sqrt{3} \\
    z^2 = -1 \\
   $$
I have them attempted to utizilize the formula

$$ r (cos(\frac{\alpha + 2\pi*k}{n})  + i*sin(\frac{\alpha + 2\pi*k}{n}))$$

where $ r = {\sqrt{3},  -1}$ and $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}$ based on the lack of a real part. Ending up with:

For $r = \sqrt{3}; \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}; k = 0 $
$$ \sqrt{3}(cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i*sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) \\
= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} + i*\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}\\
$$

For $r = \sqrt{3}; \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}; k = 1 $ 
$$
\sqrt{3}(cos(\frac{5*\pi}{4}) + i*sin(\frac{5*\pi}{4}) \\
= -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} - i*\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} \\
$$

For $r = -1; \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}; k = 0 $

$$
-1(cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i*sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) \\
= -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i*\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
$$

For $r = -1; \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}; k = 1 $

$$
-1(cos(\frac{5*\pi}{4}) + i*sin(\frac{5*\pi}{4}) \\
=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i*\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\$$

However something is wrong here, as I should most certainly also get a root in the 2nd quadrant, which I seem to be unable to find for some reason.

Comment: First root $z^2-i=\pm2i$

Comment: Your first error is that there are two square roots $\pm2i$. Your second is going from $z^2=3i$ or $-i$ to $z^2=\sqrt3$ or -1. What is the square root of $i$? It certainly isn't 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$(z^2-i)^2=-4\iff z^2-i=\pm2i\iff z^2=3i\text{ or }z^2=-i.$$In the end, you will have four solutions (the square roots of $3i$ and of $-i$).

Answer (score 1):

Don't lose track of signs, that's the key:

> I've first taken the root of both sides to come up with
>
> $$ z^2 - i = -2i $$

taking the roots only tells you that $z^2-i$ is either $-2i$ or $+2i$.

This yields two new equations, each of which will again have two solutions, hence four in total.

Comment: I suppose what I'm confused about is when I'm taking the roots of either $-i$ or $3i$ they have the same argument, which is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which doesn't seem like it should be correct

Comment: Why shouldn't it? If you take any four complex numbers there is an equation that they are the roots of, namely $(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)=0$, you shouldn't expect any particular relation between the solutions to an equation.

Answer (score 0):

your equation can be factorized into $$- \left( {z}^{2}+i \right)  \left( -{z}^{2}+3\,i \right) =0$$